# Как исправить ошибку GIT

Tags: git

Ошибка:

> $ git push form1 master To
>   https://github.com/prochka/form-captchaNumber-ajax ! [rejected]
>   master -> master (fetch first) error: failed to push some refs to
>   'https://github.com/prochka/form-captchaNumber-ajax'
>
> hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you
>   do
>
> hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository
>   pushing
>
> hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote
>   changes
>
> hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
>
> hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for
>   details.

Репозиторий на GitHub был только что создан и там нет никаких изменений

Comment: git pull не помог

Comment: $ git pull form1
warning: no common commits
remote: Counting objects: 3, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
From https://github.com/prochka/form-captchaNumber-ajax
 + 4d2510c...9ee22b6 master     -> form1/master  (forced update)
You asked to pull from the remote 'form1', but did not specify
a branch. Because this is not the default configured remote
for your current branch, you must specify a branch on the command line.

Comment: $ git pull form1 master
From https://github.com/prochka/form-captchaNumber-ajax
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories

Comment: Дополнения к вопросу стоит писать в самом вопросе, а не в комментариях.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

У вас есть там изменения, которых нет в локальном репозитории. Вы сделали не пустой репозиторий на Github, а с начальным коммитом. У локального репозитория свой первый коммит и эти коммиты, как вы понимаете, не равны (фактические у вас просто два разных репозитория).

Просто удалите папку `.git` локально, создайте репозиторий (`git init`) заново, пропишите upstream (`git remote add ...`) и после этого можно делать `git pull`. Должно помочь :)

Comment: Возможно, стоит добавить и симметричный вариант действий с очисткой репозитория на GitHub

Comment: большое спасибо за помощь, все помогло, как в сказке!

Answer (score 12):

Перевод https://stackoverflow.com/a/44442333/5574962

У меня была такая же ошибка, когда я сначала создал локальный репозиторий. Потом  перешел на ГитХаб и создал новый репозиторий там. Затем выполнил

```
git remote add origin <repository url>
```

А когда попробовал сделать push/pull, получил ту же `fatal: unrelated_histories` ошибку.
И вот как я поправил это:

```
git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories
git merge origin origin/master
... здесь выполняем команды add и commit ...
git push origin master
```